# IE bug: absolutely-positioned element with a non-transparent background colour

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have an absolutely-positioned DIV that I need to trap onclick events for. It turns out that, in IE7, the DIV seems to have no 'footprint' for things like clicking and even cursor. For example:

```
div {
      width: 200px; height: 200px;
      position: absolute;
      border: 10px solid black;
      cursor: pointer;
}
```

In IE7, that DIV has no 'footprint': it doesn't react to onclick(), and its cursor doesn't change to the pointer. Curiously, it DOES handle both those over its border - hence the large border in this example. Setting a background-color:

```
div { background-color: #fff; }
```

fixes the problem. But, in this case, that's not possible - I need the DIV to have a transparent background.

I've come across this bug in the past, but I cannot for the life of me remember the IE hack to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a transparent background image.

I would suggest using a 2x2 or bigger `.gif` that is all transparent pixels. Set it to repeat on `x` and `y` and IE shouldn't have an issue with the clicks.

```
background: transparent url(path/to/spacer.gif) repeat left top;
/* Not all of that is necessary, but I have a tendency to define it anyway. */
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem and didnt found a better solution than the transparent gif. Note that this problem also occured in IE8 for me. You don't have to use a 2x2 px gif, 1x1 px is enough.