# Issue with mousemove in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Internet explorer does not fire onmousemove events when the event target is positioned over an `<img>` element and lacks a background.

But it does register the event when the target has a background.  Does anyone have an explanation for this?  I had the same behavior in IE10, IE9, and IE8.

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/xSpqE/2/

Comment: +1 interesting question. I know this is not what you asked for, but giving the overlay a background such as `background:rgba(0,0,0,0);` seems to fix it in IE10 preview. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xSpqE/16/)

Comment: You can see that in the part of the box not covered by the image, the text does update.

Comment: ^ It is actually the other way around. The overlay covers the image. The overlay with background triggers `mousemove`. More interestingly, if you add some text content to the overlay without applying any background style to it, the mousemove event is only fired when you move the mouse above the text. Yet another IE bug that I've never meet before. I guess I just don't use `mousemove` very often.

Comment: As your question implies, the `position:absolute` with the image below it is directly related to the issue. For example, this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xSpqE/24/) with the overlay partially above the image will show that IE only fails to fire the mousemove event when you're hovering the image that is positioned below the absolutely positioned overlay.

Answer (score 2):

As OP asked for a reason, here's my breakthrough:

It's easier to explain visually, so first off let's add a click handler to the `img`s:

```
$('img').click(function() {
  $('.pageX').text('img clicked!');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xSpqE/25/)

Fair enough. You click the image in Chrome/Firefox/not-IE browsers and nothing will happen as the absolutely positioned `div` covers it.

Now try it on IE. The `img`'s click handler is fired! Therefore it shows that IE pushes elements through absolutely positioned "transparent" (no content or background) elements. More interestingly, relatively positioned elements suffer the same issue and setting `z-index` on either/both elements won't solve it either. Of course, as the image is above the overlay, it won't trigger the overlay's `mousemove` event.

An workaround is to provide some "filling" to the overlay, say `background:rgba(0,0,0,0)` will force IE to keep the absolutely positioned element at the top. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xSpqE/26/). If you need to support browsers without rgba support, use a 1x1px transparent gif as background.

I've never seen this defined in any spec nor officially reported as a bug. There's no logic or reason for absolutely positioned elements without content nor background to suffer this z-index issue, hence I'll call it yet another IE bug. Maybe reporting it on the [Microsoft forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ieitprocurrentver/threads) would be of use.

Also, related question: [IE bug: absolutely-positioned element with a non-transparent background colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378497/ie-bug-absolutely-positioned-element-with-a-non-transparent-background-colour)

Comment: `how the img ends up above the absolutely positioned "transparent" div` I think it might be when an absolute positioned element does not have a background, IE thinks it is not there. IE logic. :(

Comment: @Derek Well yes, that is what I concluded in the paragraph above that. Elements without content nor background is what I named "transparent", these suffer this z-index bug. When I said "no idea", I actually meant something in the likes "I've never seen this defined in any spec nor officially reported as a bug". I guess this is a better statement, will replace that one into the answer. `=]`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another IE fail! This is more of a workaround than an answer, but it seems to work alright:

```
var is_ie = $.browser.msie;
if(is_ie){
    $('.main img').mousemove(function(e){
        $('.pageX').text('pageX: '+e.pageX);
    }
}
```

That is in addition to the `$('.overlay').mousemove` function, so keep that too, and of course the `is_ie` check is optional.